# BS.getLine and CRLF endings

Tags: haskell, newline, bytestring

I'm trying to remove the \r from the end of lines when using `BS.getLine`. I've tried using `hSetNewlineMode` and it works with `getLine` but not with `BS.getLine`:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import System.IO (hSetNewlineMode, universalNewlineMode, stdin)

main = do
  hSetNewlineMode stdin universalNewlineMode
  -- s <- BS.pack `fmap` getLine   -- \r removed
  s <- BS.getLine                  -- \r not removed
  putStrLn $ show s

-- to test: perl -e 'print "this\r\n"' | runhaskell program.hs
```

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: For reference: This seems to be the bug report you ended up filing: https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of [`BS.hGetLine`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/src/Data-ByteString.html#getLine), I see that `'\n'` is hardcoded:

```
[...]
-- find the end-of-line character, if there is one
findEOL r w raw
    | r == w = return w
    | otherwise =  do
        (c,r') <- readCharFromBuffer raw r
        if c == '\n'
            then return r -- NB. not r': don't include the '\n'
            else findEOL r' w raw
[...]
```

This helper must be changed to use `haInputNL` from the provided `Handle` instead of the hardcoded value if we want it to take the newline mode into account. I suggest [filing a bug report](https://github.com/haskell/bytestring/issues/new).